# Differences between nodemcu and arduino processer

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu

I have an arduino Uno and nodemcu development board.[image]

I have an OV7076 camera and used with arduino UNO. It worked flawlessly with it and the code used is provided in the [Instructables tutorial][2] named as FromComputerNerd.ino.

Now i want to use it with Nodemcu. Whereas Nodemcu have a single Analog input but OV7076 uses two analog inputs [shown in][2]. So to get it I am trying to use Multiplexer. I can change the code so that it would adjust for analog pins.

But will the code be compatible with Nodemcu. Since it was written for arduino uno.If not, What changes can be done to make it compatible?

http://www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Without-FIFO-Very-Simple-Framecapture-With-/

Comment: OV7076 doesn't use any analog signals. They are all digital.

Comment: the hardware _can_ work. the sketch will need stripped of all it's AVR-specific refs like hard-coded ports.

Answer (score 1):

Camera doesn't send data via Analog to Arduino. 
A5 and A4 are I2C bus beside Analog.

NodeMCU has Software I2C protocol bus too, You can use D1 (GPIO 5) as CLK, and D2 (GPIO 4) as SDA.

see : https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/libraries.rst#i2c-wire-library

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to buy NodeMCU because it is having inbuilt WIFI, you can connect NodeMcu to internet without much effort compare to connecting UNO to internet, and the best thing is NodeMCU is arduino compatible you can do all possible stuff that can be done with UNO. We can also program NodeMCU in 'C' language using Arduino IDE directly

**Hardware comparison**

*NodeMCU*

1. 128KB RAM
2. 4MBytes ROM(flash)
3. micro USB port
4. Small Board Size

*Arduino UNO*

1. 2kB RAM
2. 32 KB ROM
3. USB type B connector
4. Bigger in size than NodeMCU

> Both are having nearly same prices.